# Retrofit with XML Converter returns null

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using `Retrofit` with `XML Converter` for the first time and my goal is to get the description field that is inside of item's tag. The problem is, every time I execute it, it returns `description` null.

My XML is:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
 <title>Tests</title>
 <description>First Description</description>
 <link>http://teste.html</link>
 <item>
  <title>Test number 5 - 1/11/2017</title>
  <description>
      Description that I want to get
  </description>
  <link> http://test.html </link>
 </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Class Channel:

```
@Root(name="rss", strict=false)
public class Channel {

    @Element(name = "title", required = false)
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "description", required = false)
    private String description;

    @Element(name = "link", required = false)
    private String link;

    private Item item;

    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getDescription() {return description;}

    public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}

    public String getitem(){
        Item item = new Item();
        return item.getDescription();
    }

    public void setLink(String title) {this.link = link;}

    public String getLink(String title) { return link;}   
}
```

Class Item:

```
@Root(name="item", strict=false)
public class Item {

    @Element(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public String getTitle() {return this.title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getDescription() {return this.description;}

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The method where I'm trying to print the description but I get null.

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Channel> call, Response<Channel> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Channel rss = response.body();
            Log.d("Controller","Description----->: " + rss.getitem());
        } else {
            Log.d("Controller","Error----->:"+response.errorBody());
        }
    }
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should check the root name of the channel. It should be "channel" instead of "rss" I think

Comment: version tag missing . instead of xml converter use xml to json converter and then you can use simple json parser as json response. Like this  try {
                                String s = response.body().string();
                                JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                                try {/*xml to json conversion*/
                                    jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(s);

Comment: @devajay why can I use a XML Converter?

Comment: @porthfind actually if you miss any simple tag in parser your perfect response will be gone in null case and you will not able to get the perfect result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time with this issue I found the solution.

The problem was that I should have add on `class Channel` in the `declaration` of each `Element` the tag `@Path("channel")`.

For instance:

```
@Element(name = "link", required = false)
@Path("channel")
private String link;
```

Comment: do you need to do that too in "Item" class ?